# Safe convert from string to date in Transact

Tags: sql-server, date

I have the following code in a stored procedure in MSSQL Transact:

```
CAST(CONVERT(Datetime, aof.Transactiondate) AS date)
```

aof.Transactiondate is a varchar(8) and should be written in the form of '20160202' or '20160117'.
Today I found out that in rare instances aof.Transactiondate can be a '1' and thus my code crashes completely.

Can I do anything to make sure that the above don't crash and sets a defult date or something instead of crashing??

Theoretically I could make sure that there is 8 chars in the varchar and then seperate the char into 4, 2 and 2 block and finally make sure that block one is between 2015 and 2016 (only relevant at the moment), second block is between 1 and 12 and third block is between 1 and 31 but that seems to be a huge amount of work.

Comment: Look at TRY_CONVERT if you are on 2012+ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx. An even better solution would be to stop storing dates as strings and store them as datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [TRY_CAST](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669(v=sql.110).aspx)

Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ISDATE() function to test for a valid date before converting the data:

```
DECLARE @TransactionDate VARCHAR(8)= 1;
SELECT CONVERT( DATE,
                    CASE
                        WHEN ISDATE(@TransactionDate) = 1
                        THEN @TransactionDate
                        ELSE NULL
                    END);

SET @TransactionDate = '20160202';
SELECT CONVERT( DATE,
                CASE
                    WHEN ISDATE(@TransactionDate) = 1
                    THEN @TransactionDate
                    ELSE NULL
                END);
```

Output:
2016-02-02

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions available in T-SQL under the [Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/conversion-functions-transact-sql) category, all of which have variants prefixed with `TRY_` which:

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

- [`CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) / [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) / [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [`PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) / [`TRY_PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You can use them like this:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CAST('2020-05-27' AS DATE)
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATE, '2020-05-27')
SELECT TRY_PARSE('2020-05-27' AS DATE)
```